# Render HTML response from remote call to the client

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a working servlet wich originates back from this template:
http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/web/servlet

So the basic rountrip works.
I added a new feature where I POST data to the servlet, construct a call/request out of the data to a remote http server, retrieve the response-html-string (the content of the website I requested) and want to show this HTML String now as response to my original POST call.

I tried it like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {


    boolean showDetails = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("showDetails"));
    if (showDetails) {
        String details = detailsLoader.loadDetails(String.valueOf(request.getParameter("value1")),
                String.valueOf(request.getParameter("value2")));

        response.getWriter().println(details);
        response.getWriter().flush();
        response.getWriter().close();
        return; // <----------------- if showDetails then this is the end of doPost
    }

    // Display the list of guests:
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

When I press the link that creates the POST event I see in the logfile, that "loadDetails" has succesfully loaded the content from the remote server, but the browser window does not refresh. Why?

PS: a simple redirect to the other side is not possible for technical reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to use GET instead of POST and I used a separate Servlet for this kind of call. This solved my problem.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String details = detailsLoader.loadDetails(String.valueOf(request.getParameter("value1")),
            String.valueOf(request.getParameter("value2")));

    response.getWriter().println(details);
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a `ajax` request to your servlet which gives to `html` content as string sent it back to `ajax` call and set it to  `innerHTML` of a `div` element.

Comment: I would rather like to understand why my approach does not work. I want also to have a page reload behavior (if possible), so that I can "go back" to the previous page.